# English versions of Géométrie et théorie des groupes and Sur les groupes hyperboliques d’après Mikhael Gromov

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am reading the paper "Small cancellation theory and Burnside problem" by Remi Coulon, and there are some references of it that were written in french.

I searched for English translation but did not find anything.

The references are:

1) M. Coornaert, T. Delzant, and A. Papadopoulos. Géométrie et théorie des groupes, volume
1441 of Lecture Notes in Mathematics. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1990.

2) É. Ghys and P. de la Harpe. Sur les groupes hyperboliques d’après Mikhael Gromov, volume 83
of Progress in Mathematics. Birkhäuser Boston Inc., Boston, MA, 1990.

Can somebody help me to find english translations in the web for these?

thanks.

Comment: Sadly, in group theory there are a lot of French-written (and sometimes German) works whose English translations are not currently available. On the positive side, if you have access to the original articles in the original language it is not too hard to get a decent translation, even just using Google Translate (mathematical language is fairly standard and easy).

Comment: Both articles were written in the early history of hyperbolic groups, and many (but not, I think, all) of the results they contain are proven in other articles. Bridson and Haefliger's book "Metric spaces of non-positive curvature" is a good English-language reference, so you could try flicking through it. Alternatively, you could edit your question to ask for English-language proofs/references for the specific results used by Coulon.

Answer (score 5):

This is a student led unofficial translation project on É. Ghys and P. de la Harpe. Sur les groupes hyperboliques d’après Mikhael Gromov

https://cheentan.com/translation-project-on-about-hyperbolic-groups-after-mikhail-gromov-by-etienne-ghys-and-pierre-de-la-harpe/